# SPServices GetListItems won't get me a result

Tags: spservices, troubleshooting

Good morning.
I have a problem regarding to a SPService function.
I doublecked it but I still won't get any result. If I erase the SpFilter Method I get a result.
Is there any mistake I could have missed? 
Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://tebaportal/websites/kressl/TTR/Scriptingfiles/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://tebaportal/websites/kressl/TTR/Scriptingfiles/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://tebaportal/websites/kressl/TTR/Scriptingfiles/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<link   type="text/css" href="http://tebaportal/websites/kressl/TTR/Scriptingfiles/jquery.marquee.min.css" rel= "stylesheet" media="all"/>

<ul id="marquee" class="marquee"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var EmptyVar  = "<li> Kein Ergebnis </li>";
    var toshow = false;
    var liHtml = "<li> NIL </li>";
    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>   <FieldRef Name='Body'/> </Viewfields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
             $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("[z:row]").each(function() {
                    liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body") + "</li>";
                    liHtml = liHtml + "<li> NIL </li>";
                $("#marquee").append(liHtml);
                alert(liHtml);
            })
        }
    });
    //$("#marquee").append(EmptyVar);   
    $("#marquee").marquee();
    //alert(liHtml);

});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.
Best regards
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your script.
It should be:

```
// in your code it was /viewfields. it must be ViewFields
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Body'/></ViewFields>", 

// the filter must be
SPFilterNode("z:row") //without the []
```